# Breaking my code by putting Dictionaries in a list. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I made a webscraper for a supermarket's website. It believe I did everything right, but somehow I messed up using dictionaries in lists, while using a for loop. My code wont even print text anymore and I can't find the solution myself.

I tried putting an empty dic outside the loop, on different spots in the code but it all seems to fail. I tried putting simple `print("test")`code throughout to see where the code fails. Still, the fail seems illogical.

```py
import time
import csv
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver


# csvFile = open('products.csv', 'w')
# writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
# writer.writerow(('name', 'price'))

pagenum = 1

base_url = 'https://www.ah.nl'
search_url = '/zoeken?query=groente&page={}'.format(pagenum)
active_url = urljoin(base_url,search_url)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(active_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)

next_page = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
total_products = driver.find_element_by_class_name('f-load-more')
T = total_products.text.split()
print(" Total products: " + str(T[3]))

var = len(next_page)-1
h = next_page[var]

while int(T[0]) < int(T[3]):
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", h)
        total_products.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
        time.sleep(1)

    except:
        print("We did it boys. Proceeding with products ..")
        break

def linkGrabber():
    items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
    print(str(len(items)) + " items found on page.")
    urls = []
    for i in items:
        try:
            L = i.find_element_by_tag_name('a') .get_attribute('href')
            urls.append([L])
        except:
            print('link for' + str(i) + ' not found.')
    return urls

yum = linkGrabber()
# for practise purposes:
yum = yum[0:3]


P_LIST = []

for i in yum:
    newdict = {}
    i = "".join(i)
    driver.get(i)
    TITLE = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/main').get_attribute('title')
    newdict["url"] = i
    newdict["name"] = TITLE
    try:
        x = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-info-content-block')
        x = x.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text
        newdict["weight/amount"] = x
    except:
        continue
    try:
        NUTRITION_TABLE = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
        ENERGY = NUTRITION_TABLE.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
        for i in ENERGY:
            A = i.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            UNIT = A[0].text
            VALUE = A[1].text
            newdict[UNIT] = VALUE
        P_LIST.append(newdict)

    except:
        continue

    print("-----------------------------------")

print(P_LIST)


# csvFile.close()
```

output:

```
We did it boys. Proceeding with products ..

1444 items found on page.

link for<selenium.webdriver.element> not found.

[]
```

I'm trying to grab all info from unique products in a list of dictionaries. After that, I'll write this info to a csv file (code in progress). I'll start using Pandas as well.

If you have any tips on structuring my code or anything else, please feel free to share them. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this `P_LIST.append(newdict)` after except condition and before `print("-----------------------------------")`

The value of P_LIST in above code is getting updated in second try except case and if that try except fails you will not get any value appended in P_LIST.

(Suggestion) Also add some debug logs in your code for better debugging in future.